# Missing required client identifier - Google Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this tutorial to implement google calendar on my Rails application.
https://readysteadycode.com/howto-integrate-google-calendar-with-rails

**config/initializer/omiauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2,
           ENV['my_long_key'],
           ENV['my_other_key'],
           { scope: "userinfo.email, calendar" }
end
```

I generated also **config/secrest.yml** (It was not present):

```
  secret_key_base: "i_generated_a_string"
  google_client_id: "my_long_key"
  google_client_secret: "my_other_long_key"
```

**controllers/example_controller.rb**

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_candidate!, except: [:redirect]
  before_action :authenticate_interviewer!, except: [:client_options]


  def redirect
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
  end

  private

  def client_options
    {
      client_id: ENV["google_client_id"],
      client_secret: ENV["google_client_secret"],
      authorization_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      token_credential_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
      redirect_uri: callback_url

    }
  end
end
```

**gems**

```
gem 'google-api-client', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'signet', '~> 0.11.0'
```

**HOWEVER**

When I go to: http://localhost:3000/redirect

I get:`Missing required client identifier.`

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the env variables with your google credentials aren't passed to the process (i.e. `ENV["google_client_id"]` and perhaps others too)

Comment: Thanks, how can I verify is they are passed? if I puts `client` from `example_controller`, I get the follo: `#<Signet::OAuth2::Client:0x00007f93e0cb4438 @authorization_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x3fc9f065a08c URI:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth>, @token_credential_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x3fc9f0657a80 URI:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token>, @client_id=nil, @client_secret=nil, @code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @issued_at=nil, @issuer=nil, URI:http://localhost:3000/callback>...}>`

Comment: You can use `puts "google_client_id: #{ENV["google_client_id"]}"` for example, if it's empty in the console then it's not passed

Comment: In which file should i put it? `config/initializer/omiauth.rb`?

Comment: You can put it for example at the first line of `def client_options` method

Comment: But generally yeah, in any file which will be executed in your Rails process

Comment: Yes, you are right. They are not passed. Do you know why? If I hard code them in `def client_options`, it works. BUT everyone can see them

Comment: How do you start your Rails server and how do you pass any other env var (if any)?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand. I `cd` into the directory of my project then I do `rails s`

Comment: Usually, there is some `.env` file (or `.ruby-env` if you use `rvm` for example) with environment variables that you load when starting your server. You can google for the info about how to load env vars file in general and some common practices for Ruby/Rails specifically.
But basically you pass env variables like this: `my_env_var="my env var value" rails s`. Then it will be available as `ENV['my_env_var']` and will contain `"my env var value"` string